# Solve `A` `B` in matrix multiplication `AB=Y` for arbitrary `Y` using least square

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate of some thread. I know there are lots of decompositions to decompose a matrix (like `LU` or `SVD`), but now I have an arbitrary **non-square matrix and I want to decompose it to product of two matrices of given shape**. If exact solution do not exist, I want to find a least-square one. If more then one solution exists, any of them would be fine.

I was using iterative methods like this:

```
A = np.random.rand(...)
B = np.random.rand(...)
for i in range(999):
    A = np.linalg.lstsq(B.T, Y.T, None)[0].T
    B = np.linalg.lstsq(A, Y, None)[0]
```

This is straightforward, but I found it converges [sublinearly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) (actually logarithmicly), which is slow. I also found it sometimes (or frequently?) "bounces" back to a very high L2 loss. I'm wondering are there improvements exists to this or simply solving `AB=Y` should be done in a totally different way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the SVD. See, for example [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Low-rank_matrix_approximation)
Suppose, for example you had an mxn matrix Y and wanted to find a factorisation

```
Y = A*B where A is mx1 and B is nx1
```

so that

```
A*B
```

is as close as possible (measured by the Frobenius norm) to Y.

The solution is to take the SVD of Y:

```
Y = U*S*V'
```

and then take

```
A = s*U1 (the first column of A, scaled by the first singular value)
B = V1' (the first column of V)
```

If you want A to be mx2 and B 2xn, then tou take the first two colums (for A scaling the first column by the first singular value, the second column by the second singular value), and so on.

Comment: That is amazing! I knew SVD is somewhat related to data/image compression but I didn't realize I can use it here. Thanks a lot!